# csv organization in python 3.6

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis, python-3.6

I have the code to import the csv file successfully and that to organize the fields (see below), I am struggling however to find a way to organize the data by field so it can be graphed using matplotlib, such in a way that I can compare ever row of ever field directly to each other.

```
import csv
with open ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ubiome samples\\ubiomesamples.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
fields = ['tax name', 'tax rank', 'count', 'count norm', 'taxon', 'parent']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using pandas/DataFrames?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ubiomesamples\\ubiomesamples.csv')
df.columns = ['tax name', 'tax rank', 'count', 'count norm', 'taxon', 'parent']
```

if you need to transpose it, you can do

```
df = df.T
```

Comment: Was just going to mention pandas, pandas is one of the best for csv files at this moment in time